# cross compile with libudev.h

Tags: c, gcc, arm

OS: ubuntu 14.04 x64

I'm trying to cross-compile a program using a device driver for ARM architecture and I am receiving errors. I've downloaded libudev-dev and libusb-1.0-0-dev.

If I use -ludev but don't link directly to the libudev.h file the compiler cannot find it. If I do link to it then the compiler doesn't seem to use it properly because it isn't recognizing the structures within it.

```
$ arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o testing ./user_periph_test.c -ludev
/opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.4/gnu/arm/lin/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/../../../../arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -ludev
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


$ arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o testing ./user_periph_test.c -I/home/user/devDriver/userPeriphDriver/test
/tmp/cc23v4yv.o: In function `read_fpga_status':
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x400): undefined reference to `udev_new'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x42c): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_new'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x440): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_add_match_sysname'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x448): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_scan_devices'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x450): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_get_list_entry'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x470): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_add_match_sysname'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x478): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_scan_devices'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x480): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_get_list_entry'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x4ac): undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_next'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x4d4): undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_name'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x4e4): undefined reference to `udev_device_new_from_syspath'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x4f8): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x510): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_syspath'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x530): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_unref'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x538): undefined reference to `udev_unref'
/tmp/cc23v4yv.o: In function `get_params_from_sysfs':
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x564): undefined reference to `udev_new'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x590): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_new'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x5a4): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_add_match_sysname'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x5ac): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_scan_devices'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x5b4): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_get_list_entry'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x5cc): undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_name'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x5dc): undefined reference to `udev_device_new_from_syspath'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x5e8): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_syspath'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x60c): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x638): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x664): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x6d0): undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_next'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x6e8): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_unref'
user_periph_test.c:(.text+0x6f0): undefined reference to `udev_unref'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

This however does build without xcompiling:

```
$ gcc -o fuckme ./user_periph_test.c -ludev
```

---

Here are the headers being used in the .c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <libudev.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: I think this is linker error, try with `gcc -o fuckme ./user_periph_test.c -Ludev`.

Comment: Running that on the regular gcc command (ignoring xcomp) produces the same error output with all of the undefined references.

Comment: If your native compiler likes the library and the cross-linker doesn't, you apparently didn't download an ARM lib, but rather the x86 version. Can you do a `file <your_lib>` to check?

Comment: That makes sense... file doesn't seem to tell me though does it?

`$ file libudev.h

libudev.h: C source, ASCII text`

Comment: I looked for the correct file `find ./ -name libudev*` in the [linux-digilent repo](https://github.com/Digilent/linux-digilent) but didn't see it there... Not sure where to find it if not here?